# n-dim volume of a scaled ball

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the unit ball with respect to an arbitrary norm $\|.\|$ (e.g. $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x\| \le 1 \}$).
I read in a book that it is easy to show:

$vol_n(\epsilon B)=\epsilon^n vol_n(B)$

(for $\epsilon >0$ and $vol_n(B)$ defined as the n-dim volume of an subset $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$)

By intuition this statement is true, but neither I have a clue how to proof it nor I found something useful on the internet.
Can anybody explain me, why this statement is so trivial?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$$vol_n(\epsilon B)=\int_{\epsilon B}dx$$

Where $dx$ is the lebesgue measure, and $\epsilon B=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x\| \le \epsilon \}$. After the change of variable: $y=\frac{x}{\epsilon}$, $dx=\epsilon^n dy$ the integral become:

$$\int_{B}\epsilon^n dy=\epsilon^n vol_n(B)$$

Comment: Many thanks! Now I see, why this statement is so obvious :D